# Javascript EJS string literal

Tags: javascript, string, ejs

I am trying to pull a graphviz format string from my database and pass to a javascript function on my browser front end. I am using NodeJS and EJS as the view engine. The following code is on my index.ejs to take the array of graph formats, graph_format and send to the viz.js function:

```
    <script>
window.onload=function(){
  console.log("converting ejs to javascrpt")

  var jscgraph=[];
  <% graph_formats.forEach(function(graph){%>
    for(var i=0;i<graph_formats.length;i++){
      var r = "";
      r=r.concat("\"");
      r=r.concat(<%- graph%>;
      r=r.concat("\"");
      document.body.innerHTML += Viz(r);
    }
  <%
  })
  %>

  console.log("now printing javascript variable 1"+jscgraph[1])
}
</script>
```

However, I get a "SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list[Learn More]  graphviz:206:24" error in the console of my browser and the lines "
      console.log("converting ejs to javascrpt")" and 
      "console.log("now printing javascript variable 1"+jscgraph[1])" do not run.

When I go to the browser debugger at line 206 as per error message, I see the following:

```
<script>
window.onload=function(){
  console.log("converting ejs to javascrpt")

  var jscgraph=[];

    for(var i=0;i<graph_formats.length;i++){
      var r = "";
      r=r.concat("\"");
      r=r.concat(digraph{
});
      r=r.concat("\"");
      document.body.innerHTML += Viz(r);
    }
```

Where 206 is the line r=r.concat(digraph{});

He is the graph_format array copied and pasted from the nodejs console for completeness:

```html
[ 'digraph{\n}\n\n\n\n\n\n',
  'digraph{\n0 [label="PUSH4", style=filled, color=antiquewhite]\n1 [label="PUSH1", style=filled, color=antiquewhite]\n2 [label="PUSH1", style=filled, color=antiquewhite]\n3 [label="EXP", style=filled, color=coral4]\n1 -> 3 [label="00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000e0", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n2 -> 3 [label="0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n4 [label="PUSH1", style=filled, color=antiquewhite]\n5 [label="CALLDATALOAD", style=filled, color=darkorchid4]\n4 -> 5 [label="0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n6 [label="DIV", style=filled, color=chocolate3]\n3 -> 6 [label="0000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n5 -> 6 [label="1896f70a8851b17a825ca0cfde09020276ebce9c64cb69476c3b2e27299ccc88", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n7 [label="EQ", style=filled, color=gold4]\n0 -> 7 [label="000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000178b8bf", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n6 -> 7 [label="000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001896f70a", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n8 [label="ISZERO", style=filled, color=goldenrod]\n7 -> 8 [label="0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n9 [label="PUSH2", style=filled, color=antiquewhite]\n10 [label="JUMPI", style=filled, color=burlywood1]\n8 -> 10 [label="0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n9 -> 10 [label="0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000023", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n11 [label="JUMPDEST", style=filled, color=magenta]\n12 [label="PUSH4", style=filled, color=antiquewhite]\n13 [label="PUSH1", style=filled, color=antiquewhite]\n14 [label="PUSH1", style=filled, color=antiquewhite]\n15 [label="EXP", style=filled, color=coral4]\n13 -> 15 [label="00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000e0", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n14 -> 15 [label="0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n16 [label="PUSH1", style=filled, color=antiquewhite]\n17 [label="CALLDATALOAD", style=filled, color=darkorchid4]\n16 -> 17 [label="0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n18 [label="DIV", style=filled, color=chocolate3]\n15 -> 18 [label="0000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n17 -> 18 [label="1896f70a8851b17a825ca0cfde09020276ebce9c64cb69476c3b2e27299ccc88", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n19 [label="EQ", style=filled, color=gold4]\n12 -> 19 [label="0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002571be3", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n18 -> 19 [label="000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001896f70a", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n20 [label="ISZERO", style=filled, color=goldenrod]\n19 -> 20 [label="0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n21 [label="PUSH2", style=filled, color=antiquewhite]\n22 [label="JUMPI", style=filled, color=burlywood1]\n20 -> 22 [label="0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n21 -> 22 [label="0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000047", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n23 [label="JUMPDEST", style=filled, color=magenta]\n24 [label="PUSH4", style=filled, color=antiquewhite]\n25 [label="PUSH1", style=filled, color=antiquewhite]\n26 [label="PUSH1", style=filled, color=antiquewhite]\n27 [label="EXP", style=filled, color=coral4]\n25 -> 27 [label="00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000e0", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n26 -> 27 [label="0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n28 [label="PUSH1", style=filled, color=antiquewhite]\n29 [label="CALLDATALOAD", style=filled, color=darkorchid4]\n28 -> 29 [label="0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n30 [label="DIV", style=filled, color=chocolate3]\n27 -> 30 [label="0000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n29 -> 30 [label="1896f70a8851b17a825ca0cfde09020276ebce9c64cb69476c3b2e27299ccc88", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n31 [label="EQ", style=filled, color=gold4]\n24 -> 31 [label="0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000016a25cbd", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n30 -> 31 [label="000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001896f70a", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n32 [label="ISZERO", style=filled, color=goldenrod]\n31 -> 32 [label="0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n33 [label="PUSH2", style=filled, color=antiquewhite]\n34 [label="JUMPI", style=filled, color=burlywood1]\n32 -> 34 [label="0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n33 -> 34 [label="000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006b", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n35 [label="JUMPDEST", style=filled, color=magenta]\n36 [label="PUSH4", style=filled, color=antiquewhite]\n37 [label="PUSH1", style=filled, color=antiquewhite]\n38 [label="PUSH1", style=filled, color=antiquewhite]\n39 [label="EXP", style=filled, color=coral4]\n37 -> 39 [label="00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000e0", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n38 -> 39 [label="0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n40 [label="PUSH1", style=filled, color=antiquewhite]\n41 [label="CALLDATALOAD", style=filled, color=darkorchid4]\n40 -> 41 [label="0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n42 [label="DIV", style=filled, color=chocolate3]\n39 -> 42 [label="0000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n41 -> 42 [label="1896f70a8851b17a825ca0cfde09020276ebce9c64cb69476c3b2e27299ccc88", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n43 [label="EQ", style=filled, color=gold4]\n36 -> 43 [label="000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005b0fc9c3", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n42 -> 43 [label="000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001896f70a", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n44 [label="ISZERO", style=filled, color=goldenrod]\n43 -> 44 [label="0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n45 [label="PUSH2", style=filled, color=antiquewhite]\n46 [label="JUMPI", style=filled, color=burlywood1]\n44 -> 46 [label="0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n45 -> 46 [label="00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000b8", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n47 [label="JUMPDEST", style=filled, color=magenta]\n48 [label="PUSH4", style=filled, color=antiquewhite]\n49 [label="PUSH1", style=filled, color=antiquewhite]\n50 [label="PUSH1", style=filled, color=antiquewhite]\n51 [label="EXP", style=filled, color=coral4]\n49 -> 51 [label="00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000e0", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n50 -> 51 [label="0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n52 [label="PUSH1", style=filled, color=antiquewhite]\n53 [label="CALLDATALOAD", style=filled, color=darkorchid4]\n52 -> 53 [label="0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n54 [label="DIV", style=filled, color=chocolate3]\n51 -> 54 [label="0000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n53 -> 54 [label="1896f70a8851b17a825ca0cfde09020276ebce9c64cb69476c3b2e27299ccc88", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n55 [label="EQ", style=filled, color=gold4]\n48 -> 55 [label="0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006ab5923", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n54 -> 55 [label="000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001896f70a", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n56 [label="ISZERO", style=filled, color=goldenrod]\n55 -> 56 [label="0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n57 [label="PUSH2", style=filled, color=antiquewhite]\n58 [label="JUMPI", style=filled, color=burlywood1]\n56 -> 58 [label="0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n57 -> 58 [label="0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000116", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n59 [label="JUMPDEST", style=filled, color=magenta]\n60 [label="PUSH4", style=filled, color=antiquewhite]\n61 [label="PUSH1", style=filled, color=antiquewhite]\n62 [label="PUSH1", style=filled, color=antiquewhite]\n63 [label="EXP", style=filled, color=coral4]\n61 -> 63 [label="00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000e0", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n62 -> 63 [label="0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n64 [label="PUSH1", style=filled, color=antiquewhite]\n65 [label="CALLDATALOAD", style=filled, color=darkorchid4]\n64 -> 65 [label="0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n66 [label="DIV", style=filled, color=chocolate3]\n63 -> 66 [label="0000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n65 -> 66 [label="1896f70a8851b17a825ca0cfde09020276ebce9c64cb69476c3b2e27299ccc88", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n67 [label="EQ", style=filled, color=gold4]\n60 -> 67 [label="000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001896f70a", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n66 -> 67 [label="000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001896f70a", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n68 [label="ISZERO", style=filled, color=goldenrod]\n67 -> 68 [label="0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n69 [label="PUSH2", style=filled, color=antiquewhite]\n70 [label="JUMPI", style=filled, color=burlywood1]\n68 -> 70 [label="0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n69 -> 70 [label="0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000163", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n71 [label="PUSH1", style=filled, color=antiquewhite]\n72 [label="PUSH1", style=filled, color=antiquewhite]\n73 [label="CALLDATALOAD", style=filled, color=darkorchid4]\n72 -> 73 [label="0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n74 [label="ADD", style=filled, color=chocolate]\n71 -> 74 [label="0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n73 -> 74 [label="8851b17a825ca0cfde09020276ebce9c64cb69476c3b2e27299ccc88f650c575", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n75 [label="SLOAD", style=filled, color=chartreuse]\n74 -> 75 [label="8851b17a825ca0cfde09020276ebce9c64cb69476c3b2e27299ccc88f650c575", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n76 [label="CALLER", style=filled, color=darkorchid2]\n77 [label="EQ", style=filled, color=gold4]\n75 -> 77 [label="0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n76 -> 77 [label="00000000000000000000000065ddc3a1f2762f3d0669bbeea44e16b2b38090a5", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n78 [label="ISZERO", style=filled, color=goldenrod]\n77 -> 78 [label="0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n79 [label="ISZERO", style=filled, color=goldenrod]\n78 -> 79 [label="0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n80 [label="PUSH2", style=filled, color=antiquewhite]\n81 [label="JUMPI", style=filled, color=burlywood1]\n79 -> 81 [label="0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n80 -> 81 [label="000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000013d", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n82 [label="PUSH1", style=filled, color=antiquewhite]\n83 [label="JUMP", style=filled, color=burlywood1]\n82 -> 83 [label="0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002", fontcolor=antiquewhite]\n84 [label="JUMP", style=filled, color=burlywood1]\n}\n\n\n\n\n\n' ]
```

Can someone please tell me what I need to do to get the viz.js function to accept this string? It accepts strings in the form of result = Viz("digraph { a -> b; }"); as per `https://www.npmjs.com/package/viz.js`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your template outputs some invalid JavaScript syntax:

```
digraph{
}
```

You need to output `r.concat("digraph{ }")`.

You could wrap your output in double quotes:

```
r=r.concat('"' + <%- graph%> + '"');
```

But this will fail because `graph` contains a new line character. JavaScript strings literals with single or double quotes don't allow that.

If you don't need to support older browsers you could use backticks instead:

```
r=r.concat('`' + <%- graph%> + '`');
```

This is a ["template literal"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) string, which can have multi-line contents.

It works in all modern browsers, but not any version of Internet Explorer. See [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Browser_compatibility) to decide if you'll be able to use it.

If you do need to support older browsers, you'll need to remove any newlines from `graph`. If it's a string:

```
var cleanGraph = graph.replace(/\n/g, " ")
r=r.concat('"' + <%- cleanGraph%> + '"')
```

Comment: digraph{} should be a string. Its not a function but a graphviz format.

Comment: I realised that and edited :-) It's not a string in your code - add some quote marks.

Comment: is that not what the concats either side is doing?

Comment: changed it to `  <% graph_formats.forEach(function(graph){%>
    for(var i=0;i<graph_formats.length;i++){
      var r = "";
    //  r=r.concat("\"");
      r=r.concat("<%- graph%>");
  //    r=r.concat("\"");
      document.body.innerHTML += Viz(r);
    }
  <%
  })
  %>` But not Mozilla debugger saying unterminated string literal

Comment: Thanks joews. I assume there should be a second + in that concat?

Comment: This unfortunately is still not working. Maybe if I put in the ` marks into the format within the database?

Comment: I placed back ticks in the string when it was being entered in the database and this seems to have helped. Thanks.

Comment: Happy to help. Can you accept the answer to show other people that this helped?

Answer (score 0):

i think here is error:-

```
r=r.concat(<%- graph%>;
```

you need to make it :-

```
r=r.concat(<%- graph%>);
```

check in your code.

Comment: sorry that was a copy paste error, I have the curly bracket for the concat function included and still the same error persists.

Answer (score 0):

digraph{} is not valid JavaScript.

If you want to use an existing variable, do:

```
r=r.concat(digraph);
```

But digraph has to be declared and initialized before.