# Retrieve text from database and inject EJS data into it

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I want to save into my database (MongoDB) text with EJS variables then retrieve it via Ajax but I don't know how I could inject the value of the EJS variables.

For the moment the text retrieved into the view stays "Hello <%= booking.nameOfGuest %>, blablablabla" instead of "Hello Louis, blablablabla".
The goal is to make automatic messages customizable by the user and to pre-fill textareas.

Ajax part (Working)

```
<script>
    $('select').on('change', function (e) {
      // Change language
      var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
      var valueSelected = this.value;

      $.ajax({
        url: "../retrieveParameter",
        type: "get",
        data: { name: valueSelected + "_message_sendkey" },
        success: function(data) {
          $("#message-accessCode").val(data.value);
        },
        error: function(data) {
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Controller part (Working)

```
const Parameter = require("../model/parameter");

exports.retrieveParameter = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const parameter = await Parameter.findOne({ name: req.body.name });
        res.json({ value: parameter.value });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
};
```

Example of a document in my database

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "642ee81165040a00eae95575"
  },
  "name": "fr_message_sendkey",
  "__v": 0,
  "value": "Hello <%= booking.nameOfGuest %> ! \nThank you for your booking <%= booking.code %> ..."
}
```

Do you have any idea of how I could inject the values into my variables ?

Thank you a lot !
Louie

Answer (score 0):

I have not use EJS myself, but you could try using a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Basically your **object** `value` **key** is holding a string

Try something like this:

```js
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "642ee81165040a00eae95575"
  },
  "name": "fr_message_sendkey",
  "__v": 0,
  "value": `Hello ${<%= booking.nameOfGuest %>} ! \nThank you for your booking ${<%= booking.code %>} ...`
}
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44905335/javascript-ejs-string-literal) is another post on how to use template literals in EJS

Hope that helps

Comment: Hello @Ricardo, thank you for your answer, unfortunately I just tried with ${} and `` but it still doesn't inject the values... Maybe I am forgetting something !

Comment: if you `console.log(`Hello ${<%= booking.nameOfGuest %>} ! \nThank you for your booking ${<%= booking.code %>} ...`)` what do you get?

Comment: Thank you Ricardo. I finally managed to achieve what I wanted by manually injecting values on the server side. I believe that when I tried to log ${<%= booking.code %>} it showed on the console "<%= booking.code %>". Anyway, the problem is fixed, and thank you again for your help ! :)